# Bootstrap 3 Carousel/Slider IE9 Support

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to get a fallback working for Bootstrap 3's Carousel and have come across this https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/6155151.

I tried to implement it by loading the file last but it does not work, How do you implement a fallback to get the sliding animation to show on IE9?

I am using a standard Bootstrap 3 build similar to this one:     http://bit.ly/1Cy3nEm

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working. I had to re-select the components I want to use for bootstrap ( http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and deselect the carousel, then compile and download.

Then its just a matter of linking the IE9 fix from here https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/6155151.

Comment: IE9Fix on github did the job for me :) tx! 
I just have to repair the css problems but JS is ok.